# Check if current time is within the timeframe using Joda-Time

Tags: java, jodatime

Novice Java developer here. I've never really used a time/date library before and I'm curious how an experienced developer would solve this. You're given 4 ints: startHour, startMinute, endHour and endMinute. Now, check if current time is within the given timeframe. Is there a more clean way of doing this than what I've done here:

```
private void checkTimeframe(int startHour, int startMinute, int endHour, int endMinute) {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalTime localTimeStart = new LocalTime(startHour, startMinute);
    LocalTime localTimeEnd = new LocalTime(endHour, endMinute);

    LocalDateTime startTime = new LocalDateTime(now.getYear(), now.getMonthOfYear(),
            now.getDayOfMonth(), startHour, startMinute);

    LocalDateTime endTime = new LocalDateTime(now.getYear(), now.getMonthOfYear(),
            now.getDayOfMonth(), endHour, endMinute);

    //Check if start/end is, for instance, 23:00 - 03:00
    if (localTimeStart.isAfter(localTimeEnd) || localTimeStart.equals(localTimeEnd)) {
        endTime = endTime.plusDays(1);
    }

    if ( (now.equals(startTime) || now.isAfter(startTime) ) && now.isBefore(endTime)) {
        System.out.println("Ok, we're within start/end");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Outside start/end");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to me it looks like a simple check of number between range of numbers.
do I would do like this

1. turn hour and minute into one number that is hhmm to simplify the comparison
2. now its a simple check between range of numbers, taking into account the case of cross-date boundary

complete code:

```
private static void checkTimeframe(int startHour, int startMinute, int endHour, int endMinute) {
    // "concatanate" hour and minute into one number
    int startHourMinute = startHour * 100 + startMinute;
    int endHourMinute = endHour * 100 + endMinute;
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    int nowHourMinute = now.getHour() * 100 + now.getMinute();

    // if range within date - simple between boundaries check
    if (startHourMinute <= endHourMinute) {
        if (nowHourMinute >= startHourMinute && nowHourMinute <= endHourMinute) {
            System.out.println("Ok, we're within start/end");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Outside start/end");
        }
    // else (cross date boundary range) - check if now date is either within range of yesterday or within range tomorrow  
    } else {
        if (nowHourMinute >= startHourMinute || nowHourMinute <= endHourMinute) {
            System.out.println("Ok, we're within start/end");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Outside start/end");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really simple and clear using ints as hhmm!

Answer (score 4):

### tl;dr

> Is there a more clean way of doing this than

Yes. This is more clean, and more importantly, **more correct**:

```java
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;
boolean hit = 
    org.threeten.extra.Interval                          // Represents a span-of-time attached to the timeline. Consists of a pair of `Instant` objects. 
    .of( 
        now
            .with( 
                LocalTime.of( startHour , startMinute )  // Returns a `LocalTime` object.
            )                                            // Returns another `ZonedDateTime` object.
            .toInstant() ,                               // Returns a `Instant` object (a moment as seen with zero offset from UTC). 
        now
            .with( 
                LocalTime.of( endHour , endMinute ) 
            )
            .toInstant() 
    )
    .contains(
        now.toInstant()
    )
;
```

### *java.time* successor to *Joda-Time*

The *Joda-Time* library is in [maintenance-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the project now recommending use of its successor, the *java.time* classes (JSR 310) built into Java 8 and later. Both *Joda-Time* and *java.time* are led by the same man, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

> I've never really used a time/date library before

Be aware that you should never use the tragically flawed legacy date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java. Never use `Calendar`, either `Date` class, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.

> and I'm curious how an experienced developer would solve this.

Use *java.time* classes.

### `LocalTime`

> You're given 4 ints: startHour, startMinute, endHour and endMinute.

A time-of-day is represented with [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class.

```
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.of( startHour , startMinute ) ;
LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.of( endHour , endMinute ) ;
```

### Current time

> Now, check if current time is within the given timeframe.

Determining the current time requires a time zone. For any given moment, the time-of-day (and the date!) varies around the globe by time zone. Either specify your desired time zone, or get the JVM’s current default time zone.

#### Time zones

Use [real time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in format of `Continent/Region`. The 2-4 letter pseudo zones such as `CST`, `IST`, and `PST` are not standardized, and are not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

Get the current time-of-day.

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( zoneId ) ;
```

### Comparing

You *could* compare that to your inputs (but you should not!).

Tip: A shorter way of asking "Is equal to or later than" is "Is not before".

```
boolean hit = ( ! now.isBefore( startTime ) ) && now.isBefore( endTime ) ;
```

#### Half-Open

Notice we are using the Half-Open definition of a spar-of-time, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This is nearly always the best way to handle spans of time.

### Temporal Anomalies

So… why not compare in that manner, using time-of-day? Because you are neglecting to **account for temporal anomalies** created by politicians, such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), war, occupation, diplomacy, etc.

To account for these temporal anomalies, apply the time zone to your time-of-day inputs. Read the documentation to be sure you understand and agree with the way the *java.time* classes handle accounting for the anomalies such as no 2 AM hour on the DST Spring-Ahead cutover, or two hours of 2 AM on the DST Fall-Back cutover.

#### `ZonedDateTime`

To account for time zone anomalies, use the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ) ;
ZonedDateTime start = ZonedDateTime.of( now.toLocalDate() , startTime , zoneId ) ;
ZonedDateTime end = ZonedDateTime.of( now.toLocalDate() , endTime , zoneId ) ;
```

See if now is within our target moments.

```
boolean hit = ( ! now.isBefore( start ) ) && now.isBefore( end ) ;
```

### *ThreeTen-Extra*

If doing much of this work, add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to access its [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class. This library is also led by [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

```
Interval interval = Interval.of( start.toInstant() , end.toInstant() ) ;
boolean hit = interval.contains( now.toInstant() ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version of @sharon-ben-asher answer:

```
fun LocalDateTime.isInTimeFrame(startHour: Int, startMinute: Int, endHour: Int, endMinute: Int): Boolean {
        val startHourMinute = startHour * 100 + startMinute
        val endHourMinute = endHour * 100 + endMinute

        val nowHourMinute: Int = hour * 100 + minute

        return if (startHourMinute <= endHourMinute) {
            // if range within date - simple between boundaries check
            nowHourMinute in startHourMinute..endHourMinute
        } else {
            // else (cross date boundary range) - check if now date is either within range of yesterday or within range tomorrow
            nowHourMinute >= startHourMinute || nowHourMinute <= endHourMinute
        }
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).isInTimeFrame(18,0,6,0)
```

Is DateTime between 18:00 - 06:00 ?